# Remove "Content" and "Discussion" from Right Now Dashboard Widget

Tags: widgets, dashboard

How do I hide "Content" and "Discussion" element in the "Right Now" dashboard widget?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: right now dashboard widget]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two methods:

### Method 1

You could remove the whole **`Right Now`** metabox from your dashboard:

```
function custom_dashboard() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    // only remove it for non-admins
        remove_meta_box('dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'core');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','custom_dashboard');
```

and then add another custom `Right Now` metabox with your custom code. You could for example check out the Wordpress function `wp_dashboard_right_now()` located in `/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php`.

### Method 2

You could hide the `.table_content` and `.table_discussion` parts via CSS:

```
function custom_css() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        // only hide it for non-admins
        echo "<style>#dashboard_right_now .table_content, #dashboard_right_now .table_discussion {display:none !important;}</style>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-index.php','custom_css');
```

and the metabox will look similar to this one in your dashboard:

[image: Custom Right Now]

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the `Screen Options` in the top right of the screen, and uncheck them from the options list to disable them from your view.